# ASA 5506W AP the wrong image upload

Tags: cisco-asa

I tried upgrading ASA 5506W AP and upload the wrong image k9w8- full lightweight instead k9w7- autonomus. How to fix it

Comment: Are you going to rommon mode?
Just reupload right image.

Comment: How to do it? You can specify the procedure step by step.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Cisco Documentation](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa95/configuration/general/asa-95-general-config/admin-swconfig.html#ID-2152-000009a1):

### Recover and Load an Image for the ASA 5506W-X Wireless Access Point

To recover and load a software image onto an ASA 5506W-X using TFTP, perform the following steps.

Procedure

- Step 1   Session to the access point (AP) and enter the AP ROMMON (not the ASA ROMMON):

> ciscoasa# hw-module module wlan recover image

- Step 2   Follow the procedure in the [Cisco IOS Software Configuration Guide for Cisco Aironet Access Points](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/wireless/access_point/12-4-25d-JA/Configuration/guide/cg_12_4_25d_JA/scg12-4-25d-JA-chap22-trouble.html#wp1048378).

Comment: How to connect to the ASA 5506W-X Series Access Point Locally?